# Multiple callouts dependant on each other in an InvocableMethod

Tags: apex, rest-api, api, callout, queueable-apex

I have an InvocableMethod apex function being called from `Flow` in which I make a total of 8 `Web Callouts`. They are all dependant on each other - so `web callout 2` uses params returned by `web callout 1` and so on...

During test and development everything was fine when I was testing the function from the `Developer Console` using the `Execute Anonymous Window` - no DML error. Although when I tried to run the function from my flow, I ran into DML errors (for me, it meant I basically couldn't run any code after my `web callout 1` - if I understand the error right.)

Anyway - for alternative solutions I have looked into `Queueable Apex` and `Apex Continuations` although I cant see how they would work for me.

Any and all suggestions are welcome - thanks, Joe

Comment: what error are you getting? `You have pending work ...`?

Comment: Correct. Whenever I try to run it from `flow`

Comment: Does the result of calllout result in DML before next callout?   All call outs have to finish before ANY DML occurs.

Comment: Yes. The error occurs before the next callout has a chance to run

Comment: Personally, I do all my invivable apex call outs in async context.  Chained queueable works well given you are doing 8.

Comment: When you say 'chained queueable' - do you mean, Apex Continuation ? Do you maybe have af link to each of your suggestions ? Thanks